# How to apply function to two columns of Pandas dataframe and two if fucntion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

I want to create a class based on systolic blood pressure and diastolic blood pressure.
i have `df` which has columns of `Systolic` and `Diastolic`. And I define a function :

```
f = lambda x, y : my_function_expression.
```

Now I want to apply the f to `df`'s two columns `Systolic` and `Diastolic` to to create a class on the new column `Blood_Pressure`, somewhat like :

```
df['Blood_Pressure'] = df['Systolic', 'Diastolic'].apply(lambda x, y : 0 if x >=90 and x <=120 and y >=60 and y <=80 else 1)
```

How to do?
is there any other way?

examples of the results I want :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In general, when working with dataframes, you should avoid `apply` and try to think of your data in terms of features (columns). Pandas does provide many vectorized operations while `apply` is not.

In your case, you can do `between`:

```
df['Class'] = (df['Systolic'].between(90,120) & 
               df['Distolic'].between(60,80)
              ).astype(int)
```

Comment: invert for expected result  (~df['Systolic'].between(90,120) & 
               ~df['Distolic'].between(60,80)
              ).astype(int)